# Deploying Custom dll Commands etc in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcobjects, deployment

Having followed the tutorial for deploying custom commands etc at the following link:

[How to deploy a custom component using a setup project](http://tinyurl.com/7u9mtct)

It's a little different to how things were at version 9.  Well I've tried many things and I guess I am missing something stupid - but I cannot seem to get the custom command to show up in the Customise dialog.
I look in the Categories.exe app - and there is nothing under MxCommands - so I definately know that it has not installed propely.  Jeez I hate these installers - they are so fiddly to setup properly!!!!  I have a suspicious feeling that the custom installer class is not being fired properly to trigger the regasm utility but I can't be sure because I haven't been able to properly debug the installation process.

Are there any glaring omissions or gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: Are you using the default location [ProgramFilesFolder]\[ProductName]\ or something else?

Comment: Yes - the walkthrough doesn't reflect the default location - as it is missing the {Manufacturer] placeholder.  Subtle but vital.  Cheers.